# Why can I play Minecraft online with my friends even though we both don't have Xbox gold?

Tags: xbox-network, minecraft-legacy-console

Everyone said we need Xbox gold, but my friend and I apparently do not. Why is that so? All I need is them to be my Xbox friend and invite them over to my Minecraft world, and we can play together and everything's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is an [All Access Event](https://news.xbox.com/2017/05/18/multiplayer-all-access-event-minecraft/) going on right now for Minecraft on Xbox.  From May 19th-21st 2017, all players can play Minecraft online regardless of their subscription.

> We’re launching a Multiplayer All-Access event with a free unlock of Minecraft: Xbox One Edition. Xbox is inviting all Xbox Live members, **with or without a Gold membership**, to play online with friends for free in any game they own during our Multiplayer All-Access event from May 18-21 on Xbox One and Xbox 360.

However, after this event you will still need gold. See [Does Minecraft for Xbox require a gold account to play with other players?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/101785/does-minecraft-for-xbox-require-a-gold-account-to-play-with-other-players)

Comment: no that cant be true, me and my friend started playing at the 15th may